# Is there a way to get a verbatim string out of an ElementTree element?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to check the MD5 hash of the text information in an XML element including all its children. This is required to interact with hipay services.

```
def CheckMD5(tree):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    body = tree.find('result')
    m.update(ET.tostring(ET.ElementTree(body).getroot(), method="html"))

    return tree.find('md5content').text == m.hexdigest()
```

Full code:
https://github.com/fabiosantoscode/python-hipay/blob/master/hipay.py#L566

My problem is that calling `ElementTree.tostring` with `method="xml"` makes ElementTree collapse closing tags of empty elements, but using `method="html"` I lose capitalization. Example:

```
>>> ET.tostring(ET.fromstring('<rt><a></a><CapName>asd</CapName></rt>'), method='xml')
'<rt><a /><CapName>asd</CapName></rt>'
>>> ET.tostring(ET.fromstring('<rt><a></a><CapName>asd</CapName></rt>'), method='html')
'<rt><a></a><CapName>asd</capname></rt>'
>>>
```

Note:

I don't need to modify this XML document at all, I just need to extract the string data of the `<result>` element. If there are other libraries which allow me to do this, please indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LH.tostring` does not collapse closing tags:

```
In [34]: import lxml.etree as ET

In [35]: import lxml.html as LH

In [36]: LH.tostring(ET.fromstring('<rt><a></a><CapName>asd</CapName></rt>'))
Out[36]: '<rt><a></a><CapName>asd</CapName></rt>'
```